# Get value from website but java code does not work. how to fix?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, cucumber

My code is not working. it gives error for this line "int temp = Integer.parseInt(currentTemp.substring(0, currentTemp.indexOf("˚ ")));" I tried several ways but I could not. Maybe a different factor affects it. Is there any idea to fix it?
Error is here:

Background:                       # darksky.feature:5
    Given I am on Darksky Home Page # DarkskySD.iAmOnDarkskyHomePage()
Current Temp: 43°
Current Temp:43˚ Rain.

java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

```
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)
at framework.DarkskyTS.etr(DarkskyTS.java:138)
at stepdefinition.DarkskySD.currentTempGreaterOrless(DarkskySD.java:39)
at ✽.Then I verify current temp is not greater or less then temps from daily timeline(darksky.feature:25)
```

@currenttempgreaterorless
  Scenario: Verify Current Temperature should not be greater or less than the Temperature from Daily Timeline # darksky.feature:24
    Then I verify current temp is not greater or less then temps from daily timeline                          # DarkskySD.currentTempGreaterOrless()
      java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)
        at framework.DarkskyTS.etr(DarkskyTS.java:138)
        at stepdefinition.DarkskySD.currentTempGreaterOrless(DarkskySD.java:39)
        at ✽.Then I verify current temp is not greater or less then temps from daily timeline(darksky.feature:25)

Failed scenarios:
darksky.feature:24 # Scenario: Verify Current Temperature should not be greater or less than the Temperature from Daily Timeline

1 Scenarios (1 failed)
2 Steps (1 failed, 1 passed)
0m5.234s
public void tempValue(){

```
    String currentTemp = SharedSD.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector(".summary.swap")).getText();
    System. out.println("Current Temp:" + currentTemp);
    List<WebElement> tempsInTimeLine = SharedSD.getDriver().findElements(By.cssSelector(".temps span:last-child"));
    int temp = Integer.parseInt(currentTemp.substring(0, currentTemp.indexOf("˚ ")));
    int highestInTimeLine = temp;
    int lowestInTimeLine = temp;
    for (WebElement tempInTime: tempsInTimeLine) {
        String sLIneTemp = tempInTime.getText();
        int lineTemp = Integer.parseInt(sLIneTemp.substring(0, sLIneTemp.indexOf("˚ ")));
        if (lineTemp > highestInTimeLine){
            highestInTimeLine  = lineTemp;
        }
        if (lineTemp < lowestInTimeLine ){
            lowestInTimeLine = lineTemp;
        }
        //int lineTemp = Integer.parseInt(sLIneTemp.substring(0, sLIneTemp.indexOf("˚ ")));
    }

    System. out.println("Highest Temp:" + highestInTimeLine);
    System. out.println("Lowest Temp:" + lowestInTimeLine );
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the full error text to your question?

Comment: Why are you using .indexOf("˚ ") ? Why can't you you use .indexOf("˚") always? Is there a space always after the degree symbol?  Let's say the current temperature String currentTemp = "-10˚"; In this case, there is no space after the degree symbol and the exception message will be `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1`. So probably, if you can make sure your degree symbol always has a space after it, maybe your program will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is answer the question:

```
driver.get("https://darksky.net/forecast/40.7127,-74.0059/us12/en");
String currentTemp =          driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".summary.swap")).getText();
System.out.println("Current Temp:" + currentTemp);
List<WebElement> tempsInTimeLine = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".temps  span:last-child"));
int temp = Integer.parseInt(currentTemp.substring(0, 2));
int highestInTimeLine = temp;
int lowestInTimeLine = temp;
for (WebElement tempInTime: tempsInTimeLine) {
String sLIneTemp = tempInTime.getText();
int lineTemp = Integer.parseInt(sLIneTemp.substring(0, 2));
if (lineTemp > highestInTimeLine){
    highestInTimeLine  = lineTemp;
}
if (lineTemp < lowestInTimeLine ){
    lowestInTimeLine = lineTemp;
}

}

System.out.println("Highest Temp:" + Integer.toString(highestInTimeLine));
System.out.println("Lowest Temp:" + Integer.toString(lowestInTimeLine ));
```

Answer (score 0):

That message is telling you that `"˚ "` cannot be found in the string you are trying to parse.  Like @Ashish, I suspect this is caused by the space after your degree symbol.  Your new line should look like:

```
int lineTemp = Integer.parseInt(sLIneTemp.substring(0, sLIneTemp.indexOf("˚")));
```

Comment: The problem with currentTemp.substring(0, currentTemp.indexOf("˚") - 1) is it will not include the character just before the degree symbol. If the value of the temperature is 43°, the result will be just 4 since according to substring method description `public String substring(int beginIndex,
               int endIndex)
Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex - 1. Thus the length of the substring is endIndex-beginIndex.
Examples:`

Comment: You are correct; I removed that suggestion from my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I did all options that you said. Unfortunately it did not work. this lineint lineTemp = Integer.parseInt(sLIneTemp.substring(0, sLIneTemp.indexOf("˚. gives error and I added in this page

Comment: @BobLerry What exactly does your line look like?  It should be `int lineTemp = Integer.parseInt(sLIneTemp.substring(0, sLIneTemp.indexOf("˚")));`

Comment: What is your sLineTemp? What I mean is after this line `String sLIneTemp = tempInTime.getText();`, what is the value of sLineTemp. That seems to be the real culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using indexOf("° "), try using indexOf("°"). It will work. The space you are putting after the degree symbol is unnecessary.

Comment: As I mentioned I did same way but it did not work. I think the problem is different. Now, I am getting the value from website as string then to verify these I need to use as integer. The problem is here. Tnx

Comment: What is your sLineTemp? What I mean is after this line String sLIneTemp = tempInTime.getText();, what is the value of sLineTemp. That seems to be the real culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. I am not sure whether my environment is the issue or not.

When I debugged that `indexOf("°")` call, I saw that it thought the parameter is `"Â°"` rather than just `"°"`. I changed it to `'°'` and it worked.

However, when running `mvn clean install`, I noticed a warning -
`[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!`

So the file was UTF-8 (not sure whether it had a BOM or not) and was misinterpreted by Maven.

Going to their FAQ, they suggest to add -
`<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>`
under `<properties>`.

I added it, ran `git checkout -- path/to/file.java` to get the original code/encoding and re-ran `mvn clean install`.
The warning was no longer emitted and the issue was fixed.